# Mysql Select between two price vaues

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select my price column in MySQL table. There are two input types, one is minimum price and other one is maximum price. According to these price values I need to select my price in DB table. So, I am using this query.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM properties 
 WHERE category LIKE '$property_for' 
   AND property_type LIKE '$property_type' 
   AND search_radius >= '$area' 
   AND location LIKE '$location'  
   AND bed_rooms LIKE '$beds' 
   AND bath_rooms LIKE '$baths' 
   AND price < '$price_max' 
   AND price > '$price_min'  
 ORDER 
    BY date_added DESC
```

But it not work for me. So, Please help me for this problem.

Comment: show us output of echo "Your Query"

Comment: You're using `like` without a wildcard, are you sure you're using it correctly? and instead of the 2 price conditions: `AND price BETWEEN '$price_min' and '$price_max'`

Comment: Are you using a case sensitive collation?

Comment: potential typo `pice_max` which error reporting would have caught the undefined variable. Plus, you might want to use `=` instead of LIKE. and add `=` to `<` and `>` operators

Comment: `SELECT * FROM properties WHERE category like 'Property for sale' AND property_type like 'Houses' AND search_radius >= '40' AND location like 'Chennai' AND bed_rooms like '5' AND bath_rooms like '5' AND price<'80,000,000' AND price>'10,000' ORDER BY date_added DESC` this is my output query

Comment: My price value in 50,000. But If no output will be come. Other than this all values are working properly. But this only irritates me.

Comment: if `pice_max` is a typo, do fix it in your question; it's misleading. otherwise change it to `price_max` and try it again

Comment: 1. Define `not working` - no output at all, getting errors? 2. Share with us examples of existing rows in that table.

Comment: am I blowing bubbles here? fix your damn typo will ya? and provide DB table schema. Guesswork drives me nuts

Comment: Have you fixed the **pice_max** typo and did that make the query run? If you have been correctly checking for errors after each mysql prepare/execute this would have been obvious

Comment: Ya I fixed pice_max.

Comment: so update your code in the question and again, provide DB table schema and example values of existing fields. Answers below are literally guessing such as `AND bed_rooms >= $beds` etc.

Comment: Well is there still a problem, if so do as @Fred-ii- suggests otherwise tell us that the problem is solved !!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly seems like we're all blowing bubbles and all answers given so far, are incorrect. I didn't submit an answer because of the question being unclear.

Comment: plus, MySQL will not interpret commas as integers unless those price columns are varchar. Your question is unclear, voting to close until we know everything about your db, as already asked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ditto, either the questioner is taking time to produce info, or has just buggered off having fixed the typo. Time to move on.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm just sticking around for a bit, seeing how this will all develop. Until we know exactly what we're dealing with, I doubt we're going to see a green tick anywhere and anytime soon ;-) I also stated above, that MySQL will not interpret commas as an integer. Too many things wrong with this picture. *Moving on very soon...* we also don't know which API they're using to connect with etc. or if anything else is failing. Very very unclear. *"But it not work for me"* means nothing.

Comment: many questions asked also and none accepted as solved. I am so NOT submitting an answer now. Edit: @RiggsFolly definitely moving on now.

Comment: I am really sorry mates. Finally I solve that problem. Its really strange...

Answer (score 0):

Use [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) validation clause to check a value between two others :

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      properties 
WHERE     category LIKE '$property_for' 
AND       property_type LIKE '$property_type' 
AND       search_radius >= '$area' 
AND       location LIKE '$location'  
AND       bed_rooms LIKE '$beds' 
AND       bath_rooms LIKE '$baths' 
AND       price BETWEEN $price_max AND $price_min  
ORDER BY  date_added DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exact output you are expecting but your query should look like following :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM properties 
 WHERE category LIKE '%$property_for%' 
   AND property_type LIKE '%$property_type%'
   AND search_radius >= $area 
   AND location LIKE '%$location%'
   AND bed_rooms >= $beds 
   AND bath_rooms >= $baths
   AND price < $pice_max
   AND price > $price_min
 ORDER 
    BY date_added DESC
```

You can use BETWEEN instead two AND condition for price

```
AND price BETWEEN $price_max AND $price_min
```

You should not give single quote with integer values such as $beds,$baths and should not use Like with integers

Comment: Actually the `%` should be inside the quote like so `category LIKE '%$property_for%' ` You might want to change that before you get downvotes

Comment: it was typo, Thanks @RiggsFolly

Comment: My problem is price value only. I want to select price value in between $price_max and $price_min value.

Comment: use BETWEEN as i mentioned in answer and remove single quote from price value

Comment: what's `AND bed_rooms >= $beds` etc. supposed to represent? those are more than likely to be strings

Comment: *"You should not give single quote with integer values such as $beds,$baths"* - that doesn't matter. MySQL will make the difference. The important thing is that the integers passed for the columns, but be `int` as the column types. beds, baths, those are most likely strings.

Comment: [Look at what the OP wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113441/mysql-select-between-two-price-vaues#comment50240472_31113441) as the echo'd query `AND price<'80,000,000' AND price>'10,000'` what do you think MySQL will spit out by not quoting those values?

Comment: AND price<'80,000,000' AND price>'10,000' MYSQL will not spit but why one give unnecessary single quote to integer values

Comment: Look again, those are commas. Think for a minute ;-)